# How to solve this Sudoku?

Tags: sudoku

Here is the sudoku - I could think the following only.

The top number box 3 coloumn wise should have some number - 6,7,3 (in some order).
The box 3 column 2 -- 2,5,8 ( in some order), and box 3 column 3 - 1,4,9 in some order.
Rest, I am really not able to identify what is wrong.

[image]

I am really clueless here, I am not able to think further. What logic am I missing here?

Comment: Try typing it into an online sudoku solver.

Comment: First, for each cell, anotate which number you can use.

Comment: If anybody wans to try to solve this sudoku himself:
http://asudoku.com/#800004000500390000702000000257643008614900537900000246400030802100079463300400005

Answer (score 5):

Hints (that should be sufficient to allow simple reduction of possibilities):

> In the second row, first box, you have a cell with possible numbers (4,6), and one with (1,6). In the second row, last column, you have a cell with (1,4) as possible numbers.
>
>  Thus, no other cells in this row can be (1,4,6), which nets you a 7 somewhere in the upper right 3x3 box.
>
>  After that, check around for other 7s - you should be able to find two immediately. Then check twos - you should find one. Carry through to completion.

Comment: But 7 can come even on the second box, 2 nd row 3rd column. Also, 7 can come on third box - 2 nd row 1st column and 2nd column. So, in the second row - series - 2,7,8 can go anywhere. Sorry, I haven't understood about 7 yet. Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @dexterous_stranger I think emrakul messed up, because 146 is taken, the only number left for the first number second row third box is 7. From there it works

Comment: @DrunkWolf By "upper right box," I meant to refer to the upper-right set of nine squares; I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @Emrakul ah that makes sense then :) I do the occasional sudoku but am fairly unfamiliar with how people describe them :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf no worries! :] There are formal names that nobody uses, and I don't even think I'm using them here... but oh well, it needed to be clearer, so thanks!

Comment: Perfect, Its easy for me to think column-wise, but I can't think from the row-wise. Generally, this kind of trick. I got it now. But, I guess, it will come only by practice. Or may be for some born genius it comes naturally.

Answer (score -5):

Is this the solution you seek?

[image]